# Add github library as dependency not working

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to use this custom ListView

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2078#!description

The steps here are:

**Step 2**. Add the specific repository to your build file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

**Step 3.** Add the dependency in your build file (do not forget to specify the correct qualifier, usually "aar"):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.THEONE10211024:WaterDropListView:7b51373b3b'
}
```

and instructions from desctiption

"2.implements the WaterDropListView.IWaterDropListViewListener in your Activity or Fragment."

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity implements WaterDropListView.IWaterDropListViewListener
```

so I did it:

in project's *bulid.gradle*:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

and in module *bulid.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.THEONE10211024:WaterDropListView:7b51373b3b'
}
```

No errors while gradle sync.
But when implementin in `MainActivity implements WaterDropListView.IWaterDropListViewListener`

I get "Cannot resolve symbol WaterDropListView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look like it is a valid library.

Within the [app/build.gradle](https://github.com/THEONE10211024/WaterDropListView/blob/master/app/build.gradle) it references

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

a library should be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

If you really want to use this I would suggest getting the code and creating your own library module within your project.

Comment: Thanks, downloaded, added as module and edited with this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library  Works now